# Google map showing previous location

Tags: php, jquery

I have an iframe with google map embedded as :

```
<iframe class="addressMap" id="addressMap" width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?&q={{$location}}&output=embed"></iframe>
```

where $location is Address1. Once the page is loaded the map shows Address1 location, on a button click I am changing src of map to another address say Address2 as:

```
$('.addressMap').attr('src',"https://maps.google.it/maps&q="+Address2+"&output=embed");
```

which seems to be working fine. But when I press browser back button the iframe reloads and shows Address1 again instead of Address2,can anyone suggest something.

Comment: Your address1 is the default address, hard-coded or taken from some kind of db. When you change your address to address2, you're doing it only on client-side, which returns to default on refresh. If you want it to remain changed, then you also have to edit your server-side information about the default address.

Comment: I am getting complete address from db, where address 1 consists of only city and state and address 2 is the whole address.

Answer (score -1):

If you want that once the user click on your address2 Button, the map keep showing Address2 even after going back (or may be even if the user leave your site and go back after a while), then use localStorage to save the fact that the button was clicked (or may be save the wanted address), example:

```
var address1 = '{{$location}}';
$(function(){
  // when page load, we check if we have a stored address, if not, we use address1
  var currentAddress = localStorage.currentAddress;
  if(!currentAddress) {
     currentAddress = address1;
  }
  $('.addressMap').attr('src',"https://maps.google.it/maps&q="+currentAddress+"&output=embed");

});

// event handler for the button
function changeAddress() {
  $('.addressMap').attr('src',"https://maps.google.it/maps&q="+Address2+"&output=embed");
  // we store the new address
  localStorage.currentAddress = Address2;
}
```

Comment: If you have read the question I have already done the same, what I am asking is once the map changes from address1 to address2 then on clicking browser back button address1 reappears on the map.

Comment: @Rahul you did the same?! how? I don't see any code that store the actual address in localStorage or in Cookies?! All you did is to change the src when a button is clicked!

Comment: I am getting complete address from db, where address 1 consists of only city and state and address 2 is the whole address. Read comments properly.

Comment: @Rahul What does that have to do with my answer? Did you test it? I read all comments before answering!

Comment: Yes I tested it and its not working as per expectation. Pressing the browser back button is still showing me the address1

Comment: @Rahul oki, then say that it didn't work, but don't say that I'm doing exactly like what you did! And don't say that I didn't read your comment! I'm sorry for taking time trying to help (it seems that it was not appreciated)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131225/discussion-between-rahul-and-b-assem).